# Why my implementation of binary search in Java slower than sequential search?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I'm asking because I basically just translate my python code to java and when I test in python the result is as expected (binary search faster than sequential search). It is not the case in Java though. Why is my binary search so inefficient?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class Chap5exe1 {
    private static boolean sequential_search(int[] iterable, int item){
         boolean found = false;
         boolean stop = false;
         int current_position = 0;
         while ((current_position < iterable.length) & (!found) & (!stop)){     //!found is found == false
             if (iterable[current_position] == item){
                 found = true;
             }
             else if (iterable[current_position] > item){
                stop = true;
        }
        else {
            current_position += 1;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

private static boolean binary_search(int[] iterable, int item) {
    if (iterable.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int mid_point = iterable.length / 2;
    if (iterable[mid_point] == item){
        return true;
    }
    else if (iterable[mid_point] > item){
        return binary_search(Arrays.copyOfRange(iterable, 0, mid_point), item);
     }
     else {
        return binary_search(Arrays.copyOfRange(iterable, mid_point+1, iterable.length), item);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 1000; i <= 10000000; i += 1000){
        int[] list = IntStream.range(0, i).toArray();
        long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        sequential_search(list, i);
        long stopTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        binary_search(list, i);
        long stopTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        String output = String.format("Sequential search:%d / Binary search:%d", stopTime1-startTime1, stopTime2-startTime2);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: The slowness probably comes from the array copy.

Comment: @M.Deinum sequential still runs faster.

Comment: @Aaron How do you suggest I change it?

Comment: Why you need to Arrays.copyRange operation? Just pass the lower and upper bound and play around.

Comment: could you change the implementation of binary search from recursive to iterative and measure the performance again. Recursive code is quite costly and in your case it will make lots of them.

Comment: @ManhNguyenHuu check [this CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156096/simple-binary-seach) which ditchs the recursive approach. Or you could keep recursing but instead of a variant array, have an invariant array and variant start & stop indexes

Comment: Since you are _searching_ in an array you don't need to make copies of that array at all. Recursive or not that copying around should be the highest source for performance hits. Just pass the array as it is to your recursive calls along with updated start and end indices. Once you've got that you can change your code to use iteration instead since recursion isn't actually needed and might even make things more confusing.

Comment: As an example of why all those copies are costly: let's only take your last iteration step at  `i = 10000000` which is 40 megabytes of data (ints are 4-byte values). By copying half of the array on every step you'll end up copying another 40 megabytes around (not to mention all the memory allocations etc.) which needs some time and effectively doubles the memory consumption of your application which additionally might cause the garbage collector to kick in and slow execution down even more.

Comment: Thank you guys. I see it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, the Arrays.copyOfRange() method call causes the overhead.  Try using the following code instead:

```
private static boolean binary_search(int[] iterable, int item) {
    if (iterable.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return binary_search(iterable, item, 0, iterable.length);
}

private static boolean binary_search(int[] iterable, int item, int start, int end) {
    int mid_point = (start + end) / 2;
    if (iterable[mid_point] == item){
        return true;
    } else if (start == end) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (iterable[mid_point] > item){
        return binary_search(iterable, item, start, mid_point);
     }
     else {
        return binary_search(iterable, item, mid_point+1, end);
    }
}
```